# How do I poach a Manager, after I step into their store?

Tags: recruitment

I own a fashion store in Hong Kong. In my experience, I need just 2 other employees if they have (Assistant) Manager experience. 1 year ago, they quit and decided to leave HK. Now only I'm left. I'm desperate for candidates — I'm overworked!

I spent $30,000 USD on job posting sites and recruitment agencies, but nobody with experience as Manager applied. I'm recompensing lavishly — see point 3 beneath. Thus I'm wondering — walk into and poach  competitor stores  in Tuen Mun and Yuen Long!

Assume I can't see who's Manager, or if they're on duty. Obviously I can't say I'm headhunting!

1. What reason can I say to speak to (Asst) Manager?
2. If Manager is not in store, what reason to give when I request their business card?
3. Now assume Manager is in store and goes up to me. What do I say? Requesting the Manager will make some people gape at me, and make me nervous! Manager was expecting customer — thus it feels too sudden, cheeky, and foxy to say

> Sorry to bother you. I wanted to kindly ask if you are interested in working at my store. I offer 15% sales commission + base salary of $120 HKD/hr ($15 USD/hr).

Comment: The last time you posted this question, your brother owned the store...

Comment: Have you considered, due to your lack of applicants, that your offer is too cheap? Perhaps you should offer more - base salary or commission or other benefits?

Comment: See https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/140834/75821

Comment: This again? This is a duplicate.

Comment: @KeithLoughnane Not a duplicate, but an attempt to clean up the question: On Meta, [Why was my second question on poaching, without brands this time, deleted?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/why-was-my-second-question-on-poaching-without-brands-this-time-deleted?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Have you attempted searching on LinkedIn?  I believe you should be able to do a region specific search for employees of specific companies.  This would allow you to contact them outside of the workplace.

Comment: @Myles i have. but linkedin doesn't let me narrow the search area enough. i need people near Tin Shui Wai, not all of honh kong.

Comment: Apologia for roll back. some people are asking about the remuneration, thus let's keep the numbers.

Comment: Hmm, the previous staff left due to the political situation or **your** management style?

Comment: What was the link at the bottom of the question for? I saw no real relevance nor why it should be included. I've removed it for now, if you feel that is wrong, please explain and rollback the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait for the current political situation to settle.

In times of economic uncertainty, people tend to focus more on themselves and their long-term future.

You could be throwing money at them to join you, but they don't know you and don't know whether your company will still be around in a month.  They'll have left a steady and safe job for short term gain and then be left with nothing.

Until the economy improves, you're probably better off saving your recruitment money and renting some agency staff to manage your store.  If they turn out to do a good job, you can consider recruiting them later on.

Answer (score 8):

## Don't, it's unprofessional.

Part of being a professional is acting in a professional fashion, and that means competing with your competitors in an honest and upright fashion. Walking into a competitor's store and trying to steal their employees away from them is very much a dishonest and underhanded thing to do, so don't do it.

If you want to recruit more employees, post more job ads, possibly including a "Help wanted - inquire inside" sign on your store window. If your current job ads aren't working, strongly consider increasing the compensation for the role - you say that your previous two employees left the country due to human rights issues, and I imagine that they're not the only ones. As a result, there are less people available to do work, and the price of labor goes up due to supply and demand.

Comment: Why would it be unprofessional, and why would it matter? Going to a store and offering employees a better job is a good thing for those employees.

Comment: I don't see how it's unprofessional or dishonest, just incredibly bold. It would be dishonest if you wanted to bribe their employees to sabotage the competing store.

Comment: I agreed, please clarify how you believe this to be dishonest.  A duty to play nice with your competitors overriding the wellbeing of potential employees has gotten several major companies in hot water in recent memory.

Comment: `"Help wanted - inquire inside" sign on your store window.` But this is unprofessional. Luxury retailers don't post signs like this.